# Regex Table name pattern to exclude certain tables in CaptureChangeMySQL

Tags: regex-negation, apache-nifi

How to exclude certain table(names) in Nifi's CaptureChangeMySQL processor by passing a table name pattern?

---

For e.g. I have 500 tables and their corresponding history tables.
Capture change should work for Employee, Order etc. but not for their corresponding tables EmployeeHistory, OrderHistory and so on. 
In short, tables with postfix 'History' should be filtered by the processor.

---

I tried

1) $.table_name:equals('DeviceHistory'):not()  - not worked

2) ${table_name:equals('*History'):not()} - not worked either

Answer (score 2):

From the [NiFi CaptureChangeMySQL processor documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-cdc-mysql-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.cdc.mysql.processors.CaptureChangeMySQL/index.html), the *Table Name Pattern* field is set as:

> A regular expression (regex) for matching CDC events affecting matching tables. The regex must match the table name as it is stored in the database. If the property is not set, no events will be filtered based on table name.

This should be a [Java regex string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Looking at the [NiFi CaptureChangeMySQL processor source code](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.3.0/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-cdc/nifi-cdc-mysql-bundle/nifi-cdc-mysql-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/cdc/mysql/processors/CaptureChangeMySQL.java), here is a code snippet of how this value is used:

```
// Should we skip this table? Yes if we've specified a DB or table name pattern and they don't match
skipTable = (databaseNamePattern != null && !databaseNamePattern.matcher(data.getDatabase()).matches())
         || (tableNamePattern != null && !tableNamePattern.matcher(data.getTable()).matches());
```

where `tableNamePattern` holds `Pattern.compile(YOUR_TABLE_NAME_PATTERN)`.

I wrote a sample program based on this and got the desired behavior using this regex string:

```
^(?:(?!History).)*$
```

Here is a demo: https://regex101.com/r/VWuSTy/1/tests

Comment: Thanks Kevdoran, it is still including the history tables. I've tried exactly what you said here . Do you think I can try something else?

Comment: @Hem It looks like the negative lookahead doesn't quite work the way we want it to when it placed after a greedy operator such as '+'. I updated my answer with something that should work. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Thanks again! Kevdoran. Not sure why the processor  is still not working as expected even after using the new regex you shared. I do understand the logic and approach you took and it should have worked. I appreciate your effort and help anyways.

Comment: I tried that regex at [regexplanet.com](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) as well. I'm fairly sure it should work. If it is not working I would recommend gathering more data (e.g., are you sure the display-name of the tables matches the internal name in the DB that is getting emitted in the CDC output?), and if you are sure it should be working maybe file a [NiFi issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NIFI) as something to look into.

Comment: Thanks again, Kevdoran. I tried few more options but no luck so far. .Do you think of any other way I could pass a list of table names to "CaptureChangeMySQL processor" that it should capture? Currently, it captures any table and inserts into History tables(OrderHistory, ProductHistory) so it ends up inserting 2 records for every one insert in the main table(Order, Product etc).

Comment: It might be a bit of a hack and would add processing overhead, but would it be possible to let the CaptureChangeMySQL processor receive events from all tables, and in the flow downstream of the CaptureChangeMySQL processor add processors to extract the table name from the event, store it in an attribute, and filter based on that?

Comment: I saw Nifi doesn't let this processor accept any input so I tried 3 regex variations to accept a list of table names but in vain.:                                                                                                    >**\b(Product|Order)\b**
                                                                        
>**(?:^|(?<= ))(Product|Order)(?:(?= )|$)**
                             
>**(?:[\s]|^)(Product|Order)(?=[\s]|$)**